# mdg:validated-method _execute asynchronous issues

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js, chai

I'm running into problems with the validated method package in my app tests. I'm calling my methods through the _execute function in order to be able to pass a userId to simulate a logged-in user while testing. The problem is that my asserts right underneath that _execute are called before the method has a chance of completing. I know my test works though because it only happens sometimes, mostly because mongo isn't always returning results quite as fast.

I looked around and found a [todos app](https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/master/imports/api/lists/server/lists.tests.js) that uses the _execute function in its tests. I can't get those tests to fail no matter how many times I rerun them, though.

This is an example of my test code.

```
describe('clients.add', function() {
    it('should add an empty (draft) client', function() {
        const res = clients_add._execute({ userId: 'CURRENTUSERID' }, { company_id: c1._id });

        assert.instanceOf(res, Mongo.ObjectID, 'method returns the newly created clients ID');

        const db_client = Clients.findOne(res);
        assert.isTrue(db_client.draft, 'client is drafted');
        assert.isDefined(db_client.created, 'there\'s a created date');
    });
});
```

`clients_add` does quite a few permission checks and can therefor take a little while before completing. Rerunning this test 20 times will fail about 5 times and pass the other 15.

Shouldn't the _execute function be synchronous? How do I make it? What am I missing?

Comment: The `_execute` function is synchronous and it's likely that the inconsistencies are caused by something else. What is the error you get when the tests fail?

Comment: There's no error other than that my asserts fail. If I log the results of the method I'm testing in both the test and the method itself, I get the log from the test first, then the method's, indicating the test runs before the method completes.

Comment: Which one of your asserts fails? What value does `res` have if you log it right after `_execute` in your test? Do you have any asynchronous function calls in your method code?

Comment: All very good questions, thanks. So it turns out the assertion of the `res` variable always passes, which would mean the `clients_add._execute` always succeeds. The assertions that sometimes fail are the ones that test `db_client`. After logging around a bit I found that apparently sometimes the `Clients.findOne` in the test is executed before the `Clients.insert` in the `clients_add` method is done. I don't understand why `res` would always successfully return an _id then, though.

Comment: Are you doing this test on the client or the server? Are you clearing the database before running the test? Could you share some of the `clients_add` method code since the problem is probably related to that?

Comment: As far as I know mocha tests only ever run on the server. I'm using https://atmospherejs.com/practicalmeteor/mocha. I am clearing the database before the test. And sure, you can see the whole method here: https://pastebin.com/xGQaRqyz. `User.get_assets` just gets the `company_id`s that belong to the current user. So all the method does is just some back-and-forth with the database, nothing too complicated.

Comment: I think I see the problem now. For future reference, please include all the relevant code (in this case, the method code is very relevant as well) in your answer, even if it is available at an external site. See more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 0):

In server code, if you provide a callback to database modification functions like `insert`, it returns the created ID instantaneously, and runs the callback only once the database has acknowledged the write. If you don't provide a callback, the `insert` call is synchronous and throws an error if the operation fails. See more about this [in Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-insert).

It seems that you have provided an error-handling callback to the `insert`-function in your method code. This causes the inconsistent behavior, since the database might not actually have had time to do the write before you call `findOne` in your test. Also, this is redundant since if an error occurs in the insert, the method has already returned and the error is never shown to the user. It's better to simply omit the error-handling callback altogether:

```
return Clients.insert(new_client);
```

Comment: This. I'm still trying to figure out how this affects methods that actually do something with the callback but that's a different problem altogether. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I don't see any scenario where you should need to use the callbacks for the database functions in server code. To customize the errors, you can use a `try/catch` block, and the second argument to the callback is always returned from the function on success, so there is no information available in the callback that wouldn't otherwise be available. For other asynchronous calls (to external APIs, for instance) you can use `Meteor.wrapAsync`.

Comment: I just had to get used to the synchronous nature of my methods is all. Thanks again for your help.